# Strange error in Python (IndexError)

Tags: python

Sorry if this is a dumb question but I am having a few issues with my code.

I have a Python script that scrapes Reddit and sets the top picture as my desktop background.

I want it to only download if the picture is big enough, but I am getting a strange error.

```
>>> m = '1080x608'
>>> w = m.rsplit('x', 1)[0]
>>> print(w)
1080
>>> h = m.rsplit('x', 1)[1]
>>> print(h)
608
```

This works fine, but the following doesn't, despite being almost the same.

```
>>> m = '1280×721'
>>> w = m.rsplit('x', 1)[0]
>>> h = m.rsplit('x', 1)[1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#35>", line 1, in <module>
    h = m.rsplit('x', 1)[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: The `x` characters are different in each case. Look closely!

Comment: Ah man! I can't see it! I'll keep looking

Comment: Oh I see it! Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

`×` != `x`. Split returns one-element list, and you are trying to retrieve second element from it.

```
'1080x608'.rsplit('x', 1)  # ['1080', '608']
'1280×721'.rsplit('x', 1)  # ['1280\xc3\x97721']
```

In second case *there is no* second element in list - it contains only one element.

MCVE would be:

```
l = ['something']
l[1]
```

With exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

To ensure that you split string to two parts you may use a [`partition`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition).

> Split the string at the first occurrence of sep, and return a 3-tuple
>   containing the part before the separator, the separator itself, and
>   the part after the separator. If the separator is not found, return a
>   3-tuple containing the string itself, followed by two empty strings.

```
w, sep, h = m.partition('x')
# h and sep will be empty if there is no separator in m
```

Comment: But why does it work in the first example but not in the second? Sorry for the dumb question

Answer (score 0):

In your second example `×` is not the same as `x`, it is instead a multiplication sign. If you are getting these stings from somewhere and then parsing them, you should first do

```
m = m.replace('×', 'x')
```

Comment: Yeah I added that line just before you commented, thanks anyway mate